# What's the C# equivalent of Java CharSequence type?

Tags: java, c#, charsequence

I'm working on converting a **Java** project to **C#**, but don't know what `CharSequence` is corresponding to C# type.

Comment: What do you need from `CharSequence` you can't get from `string` or what kind of parameter do you want to support/accept in your methods/code?

Comment: You want a similar interface in C# for `CharSequence` interface in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent in c#. Use `string` instead.

The Java [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is a simple abstraction, that allows methods with simple needs to accept a `String`, `CharBuffer`, `Segment`, `StringBuffer`, or `StringBuilder` without having to convert the others to `String` first.

It allows minor performance improvement in Java for *some* API methods.

Answer (score 0):

CharSequence is an interface that represents a sequence of characters.
To hold char array, string (immutable) or StringBuilder classes can be used in c#.

Answer (score 0):

A CharSequence is a sequence of characters which is implemented by StringBuilder, StringBuffer, String.

The closest to CharSequence in C# is:

```
char[] charArr = sentence.ToCharArray();
```

Strings are immutable in Java and C#. 
There is no mutable CharSequence in C#.

A CharSequence is basically a bridge between String and StringBuilder in Java.

C# being the best language doesnt suffer from identity crisis.

You are better off using String or StringBuilder in C#.